# I am trying to run a python script in qt creator by calling command prompt. Can anybody help me with this?

Tags: python, qt, qprocess

**I have a python Script. I would like to run the python script in qt with passing an argument.**

*For Example, python python_script.py 10
This script would return the factorial of 10.*

I want to run this command line in Qt. I've tried this way. It works. I would want to understand the working of the program. Here is the code, I have tried executing. Better Solutions would be appreciated.

'''

```
 QString path = "D:\Task_3\";
 QString command("python");
 QStringList params = QStringList()<< "python_script.py";

 QProcess *process = new QProcess();
 process->startDetached(command, params, path);
 process->waitForFinished();
 process->close();
```

'''

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Suppose I am running this command QStringList params = QStringList()<< "python_script.py"<< "10";. it doesn't execute output

Comment: What is the expected result and what do you get instead?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and clarify the problem(s) you're seeing.  As an aside, is there any reason you're using the static member [`QProcess::startDetached`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) rather than `QProcess::start`?  Subsequent calls to `QProcess::waitForFinished` etc. will have no effect.

Comment: In addition to what @G.M. has said, it seems that you're using single backslashes which are treated as escape symbols. It should be `QString path = "D:\\Task_3";` or `QString path = "D:/Task_3";`

Comment: @G.M. i am not aware of QProcess and a beginner in Qt. I have copied this code and couldn't understand its working i.e. how it takes the input as a script and arguments. Is there any other similar and easy way of running this same program.

Comment: i shall re-edit the question.

Comment: I have edited the question.If it is still not understandable. please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("python", {"python_script.py"});
process.waitForFinished();
```

1. If you want to wait for the command to finish, you cannot start it detached. You should use the [start method](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qprocess.html#start) instead for that. For example:
2. Backslashes may need to be escaped by backslashes, although if you switch to the start method as above, this may not even be relevant.
3. In general, in cross-platform Qt applications, you ought to avoid hard-coding operating system specific paths, like a specific Windows path. You ought to offer a cross-platform solution, like running it from the script directory or some sort of file selection QDialog to let the user to select the path for running. This depends on the exact use case.
4. Slight nitpick, but you either do not need a heap instance (pointer) for the `QProcess` instance or you ought to parent it so that it does not leak memory.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: "It does not work" does not work when trying to help. Need details.

Comment: I didn't mean to disrespect you.  I said the code doesn't work. I see the issue in finding the path. The code executes and there is not out put after execution.

Comment: You will need to read the error output: doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qprocess.html#readAllStandardError - your setup is likely broken. Python path or python module path, etc, some path may not be set up correctly.